# How to get count for each result in this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table where each row tracks details about when a link was clicked. This query shows the top 5 pages that the user was on when they clicked the link:

```
$pop_pages = ("SELECT url FROM clicks WHERE link = '$link_id' GROUP BY url ORDER BY url ASC LIMIT 5");

foreach($pop_pages as $page) {

$page_string = $page_string."<li>".$page->url."</li>";

}
```

This will make a list of the top 5 most frequently clicked URL's. How do I add a count for how many times it was clicked in this query?

Something like:

```
$page_string = $page_string."<li>".$page->url." (X clicks)</li>";
```

Comment: please improve your question it is really difficult to understand.. What's the difference between url and link in your query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pop_pages = ("SELECT url, count(url) as c FROM clicks WHERE link = '$link_id' GROUP BY url ORDER BY url ASC LIMIT 5");

foreach($pop_pages as $page) {

$page_string = $page_string."<li>".$page->url." (".$page->c." clicks)</li>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$pop_pages = ("SELECT url, COUNT(*) as count FROM clicks WHERE link = '$link_id' GROUP BY url ORDER BY url ASC LIMIT 5");

foreach($pop_pages as $page) {

  $page_string = $page_string."<li>".$page->url." (".$page->count." clicks)</li>";

}
```